# Combine Related Resources With TastyPie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

How can I combine multiple Resources in TastyPie? I have 3 models I'd like to combine: users, profiles and posts.

Ideally I'd like profiles nested within user. I'd like to expose both the user and all of the profile location from UserPostResource. I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        fields = ['username','id','date_joined']

        #Improper Auth
        authorization = Authorization()

class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'profile'


class UserPostResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'user', full=True)


    class Meta:
        queryset = UserPost.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userpost'

        #Improper Auth
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Here are my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    location =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank= True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tastypie fields (when the resource is a `ModelResource`) allow passing in the `attribute` kwarg, which in turn accepts regular django nested lookup syntax.

So, first of all this might be useful:

```
# in UserProfile model (adding related_name)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
```

and given the above change, the following:

```
from tastypie import fields

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    # ... 
    website = fields.CharField(attribute = 'profile__website' )
    description = fields.CharField(attribute = 'profile__description' )
    full_name = fields.CharField(attribute = 'profile__full_name' )
    # ...
```

will expose the data from `UserProfile` model within the `UserResource`.

Now if you'd like to expose a list of locations (coming from `UserPost`) within the `UserResource` you will have to override one of `Tastypie` methods. According to the documentation a good candidate would be the [`dehydrate()`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate) method.

Something like this should work:

```
# in UserPost model (adding related_name)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    # ....
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        posts = bundle.obj.posts.all()
        bundle.data['locations'] = [post.location for post in posts]
        return bundle
    # ...
```

Comment: UserProfile is related to User and UserPost is related to User, could you provide an example in this case?

Comment: If you could paste your models and say which attributes of which model you'd like to expose via the `UserResource` then yes.

Comment: Awesome kgr, thanks for the great answer. This really helped me wrap my head around Tastypie a bit more.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help :) As a side note I can tell you can do really much with Tastypie and I recommend it (it's much better than Piston for example) so figuring out its oddities is a time well-invested.

Comment: Does this only work if `related_name` is also present on the correspondig ForeignKey field in the Model? (And has the same value?) That would be quite worth mentioning.